SwiftUI: id-modifier vs. tag-modifier
From what the documentation says, they seem to fulfill similar purposes.


What's the difference between the id-modifier and the tag-modifier in SwiftUI?
When shall I use which?

Look at the documentation of each

Their documentations very clearly point out how they are different. They do not have "similar purposes" at all. Please explain what you have learned from the documentation.

The documentation on id() says Binds a view’s identity to the given proxy value and that the identity of the view is reset when it is changed. At least to me, it is not at all clear what that means or how this should be used. I think this is a very valid question.

Use .tag(_:) for selection. The tag and Picker docs explain this. What can be confusing is if tag is not set, then ForEach will use the id in place of a tag.
Use .id(_:) to override View identity. E.g. if you changed the id after the UI described by this View is shown, SwiftUI would teardown all the UI objects, clear all the state, and rebuild as if it is completely different UI. Generally it isn't needed, however it is needed to force reload a badly implemented View that doesn't update correctly, e.g. it's needed for PhotosPicker because it doesn't update when changing the matching param between photos and videos. By default View identity is the path to the View in the hierarchy, and each id makes up that path.
